# Is it possible to delete a variable declared using const?

Tags: javascript

Given

```
const localName = "local_name";
delete localName; // true
console.log(localName); // "local_name"
```

Is it possible to delete a variable declared using `const`?

Comment: Nö its not possible do delete or redefine a constant inside the constants scope

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable: *"The point is the `delete` operator removes a property from an object. It cannot remove a variable."* So the answer is no (independently of whether `const`, `var` or `let` was used).

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`delete` is used to delete properties from an object.

```
delete foo;
```

will try to delete the property `foo` from the *global object*. Declared variables can never be removed with `delete` (no matter if you use `const`, `let` or `var`), and there is no other way to remove a "variable" (binding) ([see @T.J.'s comment for some more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424019/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-variable-declared-using-const/42424137?noredirect=1#comment71993726_42424137)).

Related: [How to unset a JavaScript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-to-unset-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: (I know *you* know this, but for lurkers...) Amusingly, the *reason* you can't delete a `const`, `let`, or `class` from global scope with `delete` is different from the reason you can't delete a `var` from global scope, although the underlying motivation for the spec decision is largely the same (I suspect). But since you can't `delete` either... :-) You can't use `delete` to remove a `const`, `let`, or `class` from the global object because they aren't *on* the global object in the first place! (Whereas a global `var` is, but it's not deleteable.)

Comment: Yeah, my assumption was that even if `const` et al was added to the global object, it wouldn't be allowed, just like with `var`.

Comment: @FelixKling Is conclusion that `const` variable declared cannot be changed whatsoever?

Comment: @guest271314: That's why it's `const` :)

Comment: @FelixKling Is there no workaround for the behaviour?

Comment: @guest271314: Besides *shadowing* the constant I don't think there is.

Comment: What is _shadowing_? Realms?

Comment: @guest271314:  Just scope: `const foo = 42; (function() { const foo = null; console.log(foo); }());`.