# 'let', 'const', and 'var' on global functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When defining a global function, should I use `var`, `let`, or `const`?

```
var fn = function () {};
let fn = function () {};
const fn = function () {};
```

I'm here thinking primarily of global functions in the C/Pascal sense, i.e. a function that is available/visible, by name, in the rest of the current file.

When I was learning JavaScript we used either `var fn=..` or `functino fn ()..`, and I'm trying to update my knowledge since browsers are now supporting ECMAScript 6 natively.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just to define a function I can use by name anywhere in the current module. I was thinking that the function name wouldn't change once written, but I can imagine situations where that might not be the case.

Comment: Why would the function name or reference change? The selection of option would depend on the context of use of identifier; whether function or other value that is referenced by identifier, yes? `const` type cannot be changed, `const` cannot be deleted.

Comment: That is, that am aware of, `const` initial type of object cannot be changed to another type, and `const` cannot be de-referenced or deleted from current scope, see [Is it possible to delete a variable declared using const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424019/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-variable-declared-using-const?)

Comment: The question is inaccurate on the most important part, 'anywhere in the current module'. Module scope isn't global scope.

Comment: For the same reason that any global variable changes value, but e.g. (lame example) assigning a global `logfn` either `colorlogfn` or `nocolorlogfn`..

Comment: Why would you need to change a _constant_ variable? If the variable is an array or object, the properties of the array or object can be changed. What would be the purpose for changing the name of a function reference? _"either `colorlogfn` or `nocolorlogfn`"_ `colorlogfn` and `nocolorlogfn` are two different functions, yes?

Comment: @estus sorry, but you're correct that I don't know how to define a module scoped vs a global scoped variable...

Comment: It *is* module scope and not global if you're using modules. To make a global in modular environment, it should be `window.fn = ` or `global.fn = ` for Node. It's totally unclear what's your case and what you're trying to do, that's the reason why the question attracts downvotes and closing votes.

Comment: _"I'm here thinking primarily of global functions in the C/Pascal sense, ie. a function that is available/visible, by name, in the rest of the current file."_ Not certain what question is?

Comment: @estus thanks for the explanation. I noticed most of the close votes were for "primarily opinion based", which wasn't anywhere near my intention..

Comment: _"which wasn't anywhere near my intention."_ Intent is irrelevant. The question is not clear. What is the issue that you are trying to resolve?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm just trying to learn to use es6 correctly/idiomatically. (1 close vote for unclear, 3 for opion). Please take my lack of clarity as a lack of understanding, which it is, and not that I'm trying to be obtuse..

Comment: "correctly" is different from "idiomatically". The context is just as relevant as the concept of ability to select an appropriate method to declare a variable. It depends on the context in which you are performing tasks and expecting specific outcomes of procedures. You find or define your own "correct" approach, barring syntax errors or absurd results or side-effects.

Comment: 'global functions in the C/Pascal sense' - it's not called global in JS, it's module scope, and it doesn't really differ from function scope or other local scope in JS. it's just `function` or `const` if it needs to be declared once (`const` provides a safeguard against accidental reassigning) or `let` if it should be conditionally assigned. Notice that `function` declaration is hoisted, so it can be moved to the bottom for readability, while `const` and `let` can't.

Comment: @estus thanks, that cleared up a whole bunch of issues :-)

Comment: The last edit to Question, from perspective here, provides context to inquiry.

Comment: @peter-mortensen thanks for the edits (although I'm pretty sure let/const/var implies "or" not "and"). I think (and google seems to agree) that "es6" is more common than ECMAScript 6, but I'm sure the latter is technically more correct (obligatory, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: I would recommend you to use `const`. Why?

*(In the following examples, assume we are in a browser environment.)*

### Function declarations/statements

They are hoisted and become properties of the global object.

```
fn(); // No error
function fn() {}
console.log('fn' in window); // true
```

### Function expressions with `var`

They are not hoisted, but a variable declared in the global scope always becomes a property of the global object.

```
fn(); // TypeError
var fn = function () {};
console.log('fn' in window); // true
```

### Function expressions with `let`

They are not hoisted, they do not become properties of the global object, but you can assign another value to your variable. Since JavaScript is loosely typed, your function could be replaced by a string, a number, or anything else.

```
fn(); // ReferenceError
let fn = () => {};
console.log('fn' in window); // false
fn = 'Foo'; // No error
```

### Function expressions with `const`

They are not hoisted, they do not become properties of the global object and you cannot change them through re-assignment. Indeed, a constant cannot be redeclared.

```
fn(); // ReferenceError
const fn = () => {};
console.log('fn' in window); // false
fn = 'Foo'; // TypeError
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `const` unless there is a compelling reason you need to use `let`. You should stop using `var` entirely.

But usually, I'd avoid function expressions entirely and use a function declaration instead:

```
// Use this
function myFunc() {
  // do stuff
}

// Instead of this
const myFunc = function() {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: no, it depends, if the value (function) changes.

Comment: And that would be a compelling reason. I assume he understands that a `const` is indeed immutable.

Comment: Any particular reason why you would use a function declaration instead of a fn. expression?

Comment: Personal style, really. I prefer declarations because of hoisting. Some people tend to find that unpredictable behavior, but I disagree. Obviously, there are situations where function expressions are necessary, but I tend to use declarations where I can.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the correction. Real immutability in JS requires more work than just throwing `const` in front of your variable. That said, you should be attempting to write your code in such a way that all variables are `const`s

Comment: @Brennan _"you should be attempting to write your code in such a way that all variables are `const`s"_  What would be purpose of defining _all_ variables using `const`? `const n = 1; n += 1;//Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: Javascript is well suited to writing in a functional style, which means that you shouldn't *need* to have an incrementer variable like that. One of the things that has made me a better javascript developer is attempting to write as functionally as possible. Not *everything* can be `const`, there are going to be exceptions, but you'd be surprised at how little you need `let` if you just think about your code a different way

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I feel confident that one could solve just about any problem with only `const` variables.

Answer (score 3):

Eric Elliot writes:

> `const` is a signal that the identifier won’t be reassigned.
>
> `let`, is a signal that the variable may be reassigned, such as a
>   counter in a loop, or a value swap in an algorithm. It also signals
>   that the variable will be used only in the block it’s defined in,
>   which is not always the entire containing function.
>
> `var` is now the weakest signal available when you define a variable
>   in JavaScript. The variable may or may not be reassigned, and the
>   variable may or may not be used for an entire function, or just for
>   the purpose of a block or loop.

From https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75

So, best practice is to use `const` because function shouldn't be redeclared.