# How to use async find method in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is my current codes written in express.js.

```js
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
 const username = '';
  await User.findOne({_id: req.body.id,}, (err, user) => {
  if (err) // how to process this part?
  username = user.username;
  });
});
```

Comment: What is purpose of `username = user.username`?

Comment: yeah, I need to get username .

Comment: Are you expecting same identifier `username` defined at `const username = '';` to be assigned at `username = user.username;`?

Comment: yep, i need to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can `return` `user.username` from `.findOne()` function. Note, a variable identifier declared using `const` cannot be reassigned, see [Is it possible to delete a variable declared using const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424019/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-variable-declared-using-const).

```
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const username = await User.findOne({_id: req.body.id,}, (err, user) => {
    // return empty string or other value if `err`
    if (err) return "" // how to process this part?
    return user.username;
  });
});
```