# How do I make an ArrayBuffer immutable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I make the content of an `ArrayBuffer` immutable in Javascript? The `Object.freeze()` method does not seem to be working. Is there any method to achieve it? Would it be even possible?

Comment: it already is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer "You cannot directly manipulate the contents of an ArrayBuffer"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I'm sorry but I know that already. What I am asking in this question is, **the way to prevent an `ArrayBuffer` from being manipulated THROUGH _Views_** such as _Typed arrays_ and `DataView`s. So that I can fill an `ArrayBuffer` with its initial data, and then _freeze_ it.

Comment: @guest271314   I'm trying to prevent an `ArrayBuffer` from being manipulated through _Views_.

Comment: sheesh okay well ya didn't say that bud

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I apologize if it sounded rude. I never meant to be rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `ArrayBuffer` to an immutable string as a `data URI` defined using `const`

```
const reader = new FileReader;

reader.onload = () => { const ab = reader.result // `ab` cannot be changed }

reader.readAsDataURL(new ArrayBuffer(123));
```

See [Is it possible to delete a variable declared using const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424019/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-variable-declared-using-const)?

Comment: Oh, an _immutable copier_ solution. The original `ArrayBuffer` would be no longer able to be accessed, and only the immutable objects clone it out.. Seems great, but why did you removed your `Promise.resolve()` solution?

Comment: The `Promise.resolve()` approach needs to be adjusted. How is the `ArrayBuffer` declared?

Comment: Correction first: "why did you *remove".  --  The `ArrayBuffer` can be declared (created) in any ways.

Comment: The linked answer describes why `const` `let` declarations cannot be deleted with `delete`. Where the `ArrayBuffer` is not declared using `const` or `let` you can try to `delete` the variable. Else, use the string approach